# Phonegap application would not work in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a very interesting problem. I have a phone-gap application that I am building. It works fine when we run it in the android environment, or even when we open index.html in firefox. But when I try to run this on an iPad simulator in Xcode, it fails. 
The application installs fine and displays the start up page correctly. The next thing my application requires is to open a job attached in the email. But as soon as we do that, thats when it starts failing. It does not display the body text. The header and the footer are displayed fine. 
To me this does not look like any javascript error because I am able to run this code on other platforms. I think its got to do with some css I am using which might not be compatible with iOS. Also, I have this other problem that my code will not run on any version except phone gap-1.3.0. I am not sure if that has anything to do with this too. 
Anyways, I would like to know your thoughts on this.

Comment: My thoughts on this: Where is the code?

Comment: Or it could be the fact your trying to read emails when you doing have the clearence? Add some debugging code to your app

Comment: The code is quite big and its against company policy to post it online. I know for sure its not reading emails when I am opening the downloaded attachment. The application itself does not read the email, it just reads a particular file that you get through an email.

Comment: @uditTheProgrammer: You could post at least relevant parts of the code,, otherwise we can only guess and its impossible to give a proper answer!

Comment: well even if I post anything, you will just ask me ten more questions on what it is because the code is quite big and everything is sort of connected. Also, as I said earlier the problem is not with the code because it runs fine on other platforms. At this point, I am guessing a lot too to fix this and I don't mind if you guys throw out some ideas. 
Also, if you had such a problem before please let me know what you did to fix it.

Comment: alright you guys might wanna check this out. This was the offending code:
$.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;
I am not sure why and how this causes problem with loading up my body text but please let me know if you know anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

ok the offending code was found to be the following:
 $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true; 
I just stumbled across this and I am not sure why its breaking my app. Anybody got any ideas. 
After commenting this code out, my app worked fine.